# Laravel View ajouter_utilisateur not Found

Tags: laravel-blade

`I am returning a view in a laravel app Here is the route`
Route::get('/',[utilisateurController::class, 'liste_utilisateur']);
Route::get('/delete-utilisateur/{id}',[utilisateurController::class, 'delete_utilisateur']);
Route::get('/update_utilisateur/{id}',[utilisateurController::class, 'update_utilisateur']);
Route::post('/update/traitement',[utilisateurController::class, 'update_utilisateur_traitement']);

Route::get('/ajouter',[utilisateurController::class, 'ajouter_utilisateur']);
Route::post('/ajouter/traitement',[utilisateurController::class, 'ajouter_utilisateur_traitement']);

`and then in the controller`
class utilisateurController extends Controller
{

```
public function liste_utilisateur()
{
    $utilisateurs = Utilisateur::paginate(5);
    return view('ajouter_utilisateur' , compact('utilisateurs'));
}

public function ajouter_utilisateur()
{
    return view('ajouter_utilisateur');
}
```

I am returning a view in a laravel app Here is the route

Route::get('roles', 'CreateList@create');

and then in the controller

get();
        return view('roles.blade.php', compact('role_id', 'name'));

    }
}

Finally I do have a roles.blade.php in my Resources/views folder but when I go to the route I get the

`InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php line 137:
View [ajouter_utilisateur.php] not found. 
`